# * old SSL session ID is stale, removing * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse / Guzzle / Error

Tags: guzzle

Why does this problem occur?
I am using php guzzle
"Accept"=>"text/event-stream",
"Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate",
[here is the result of the request I got from some programs, there is no problem here, but when using php on windows I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqUZ9.png)